# Cannot open zip created with shell script

Tags: scripts, file-format, filename

I try to make a backup script, but when i create a zip with the script, and use `cd myzip` it sais that it dosnt exitst even when i can see it on the server with FileZilla.

This is my script:

```
TIME=BACKUPMC-`date +%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M`.zip
DEST="/home/daixhosting/d1"
zip -r $TIME /home/daixhosting/d1
```

Does someone know what the cause can be?

Comment: When i try to unzip it, it cant locate the file, i can only see it, but cannot do anything with it.

Comment: what's the name of the file?

Comment: Its as the script sais: BACKUPMC-02-08-2015-17:15.zip

That was the time i runned the script

Comment: Try `unzip BACKUPMC-02-08-2015-17:15.zip` and then check..

Comment: @heemayl i can't do that couse it cannot find the file.

Comment: Whats the output of `find / -type f -name 'BACKUPMC-02-08-2015-17:15.zip'` ?

Comment: @heemayl Theres actually no output from it...

Comment: That means there is no such file..are you sure about the file names ?

Comment: @heemayl Even if i try to open/download the file with FileZilla it sais that theres no file with that name, as you can see here: [link](http://trixia.dk/c.png)

Comment: go to `/root` and check if the file exists or not..if not then filezilla is somehow making a mistake.

Comment: @heemayl the file is there.

Comment: Now run `file THE_NAME_OF_FILE`

Comment: Also run `for i in /root/*; do printf '%s\n' "$i" | od -c; done`

Comment: @heemayl when i run the `file` command it gives me this: http://pastebin.com/kjMyeC2A

Comment: Run `for i in /root/*; do printf '%s\n' "$i" | od -c; done`

Comment: I did that, but still wont work

Comment: Give me the output..

Comment: @heemayl here you go http://pastebin.com/heRqTnWP

Comment: That means the file does not exist..can you add a screenshot of `ls -al /root`

Comment: @heemayl This is wired. Now the file is gone... it was there in the beginning...
Should i run the script again?

Comment: Yes, run and check again..

Comment: Damn... this is the worst... i was looking on the wrong server.. The file is still there. This is the output from the right server: http://pastebin.com/8UES9Yt0

And the file command gives me this: http://pastebin.com/uXu2AZux

Comment: You have files with carriage return in them..thats the reason you were not finding them.. run this command and then check in the normal manner.. at first go to the directory containing files using `cd` and then run `for file in *; do mv -i "$file" "$(sed 's/\r//g'<<<"$file")"; done`

Comment: @heemayl It gives me this when i try running the command: http://pastebin.com/7f5dYMXq

Comment: Try it in `bash`

Comment: @heemayl i might think i should run it like this: http://pastebin.com/M4pzpDnw

And that gave me no output, and it still not working.
Am i running it right?

Comment: At first go to the directory, then run `bash`, then run `for file in *; do mv -i "$file" "$(sed 's/\r//g'<<<"$file")"; done`

Comment: I have added an answer..please select that as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Answer (score 1):

You have carriage return `\r` in the file names, as a result you are not being able to parse the files using usual manner.

To remove all the `\r` characters from the file names run the following command in `bash` from the directory containing the files :

```
for file in *; do mv -i "$file" "$(sed 's/\r//g'<<<"$file")"; done
```

Now all the files should not have `\r` in them , now you can `zip` them using usual manner e.g. :

```
zip -r foo.zip /home/foobar/spam/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the zip file to a file name without the ":".

If that's not the problem, consider that the file could be corrupted. So, you'll try to repair it and maybe save a part of the information. Some way for that is, for example,

```
zip -F broke.zip --out pleasework.zip
```

or

```
zip -FF broke.zip --out pleasework.zip
```

Comment: i tried that at the sais that it can't find the zip fil.